# Performance issue on MySql join where value between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have two tables. The ipaddress range table is in the following format:

```
ip_start BIGINT
ip_end BIGINT
country VARCHAR
```

(IP addresses have been converted to a number)

The second table contains the order details and the users ip_address also in the same number format.

I am trying to return the orders table together with the country of the ipaddress.

Doing the following join works, but the query takes several minutes on about 5000 rows.

```
SELECT *  FROM  orders o
LEFT JOIN iplookup ip
  ON o.ip_address >=  ip.ip_start AND
     o.ip_address <= ip.ip_end
```

How can I improve the performance of this query?

`EXPLAIN` responds with:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE      o     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL NULL   45775 Using where
1  SIMPLE      ip    ALL  ip_start,     NULL NULL NULL   140712
                          ip_end,
                          star_end_idx
```

Comment: What does `explain select...` says for the above query ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty It just tells me that both are simple queries and how many rows there are per table. The ipaddress table is quite large obviously. Containing some 140k entries.

Comment: You are missing indexes for sure, the query looks good. Add the following indexes after taking a backup of the tables `alter table orders add index ip_address_idx(ip_address);  alter table iplookup add index star_end_idx(ip_start,ip_end)`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks, but they are all indexed. Still takes around 5 minutes.

Comment: please post the explain result into the question, without seeing the result hard to say anything.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Explain results are now part of the question.

Comment: looks like the table `orders` does not have any index on `ip_address` check if there is one. `show indexes from orders` then add the index for `ip_address` on `orders` also its better to use `inner join` instead of `left join` if you are looking to find only matching records. Make sure that the joining keys between 2 tables are of same datatype. In `iplookup` they are bigint so it needs to be same in `orders` table for `ip_address`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty There is an index on `ip_address`, but I think it is not relevant to the query, because the column is the source against which the other table is matched. I assume there is an issue in how the second table is matched. Since there are thousands of rows that match bigger than and also smaller than criteria, and until that is filtered down to just one row takes a long time. But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I have realized that the query actually executes very quickly. This seems to be an issue with phpMyAdmin rendering the data as the results are fast using the MySql console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure but I used to read some article about this

If I remember you should use `WHERE` clause to filter table you want before join

For Example

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT *
     FROM iplookup ip
     WHERE ip.start BETWEEN ......... AND ...........
) ip  ON o.idColoum = ip.idCol
```

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 needs 32 bits (`INT UNSIGNED`); IPv6 needs 128 bits (`BINARY(16)`); `BIGINT` is not appropriate.

```
o.ip_address >= ip.ip_start AND
o.ip_address <= ip.ip_en
```

cannot be optimized by any subquery or INDEX.

You have no overlapping ip_start/end ranges, correct?  In that case, [my blog on ip ranges](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) covers how to do the task *much* more efficiently than what you have encountered.  It requires re-designing your table to have only ip_start values, and the blog provides the Stored Routines necessary for IPv4 and for IPv6.